# Ant conditional property expansion not working as expected

Tags: java, ant, conditional-statements, target

So, I have this setup in ant:

```
<target name="context">
    <echo>docbase: ${docbase.dir}</echo>
    <antcall target="_context.docbase"/>
    <antcall target="_context.nodocbase"/>
</target>

<target name="_context.docbase" if="${docbase.dir}">
    <echo>Context with docbase</echo>
    <context.md docbase="..."/>
</target>

<target name="_context.nodocbase" unless="${docbase.dir}">
    <echo>Context without docbase</echo>
    <context.md/>
</target>
```

And when `docbase.dir` is set to true or false things work as you'd expect.  But when `docbase.dir` is set to an actual value (e.g., `/tmp/docbase`) for some reason it hits the `_context.nodocbase` target instead of the expected `_context.docbase` target.

Reading the docs it implies that if the expanded property isn't one of the "truthy" for "falsey" constants then it will just interpret it as before, but this isn't what I'm seeing.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I use a different approach?

Note: I'm using Ant 1.8.2 (and conditional parameter expansion started in 1.8.0).

Comment: What version of ant are you using?

Comment: Good point, I added a note.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html

> As of Ant 1.8.0, you may instead use property expansion; a value of true (or on or yes) will enable the item, while false (or off or no) will disable it. Other values are still assumed to be **property names** and so the item is enabled only if the named property is defined.

This is some really subtle information here.  So what's going on in your code is `${docbase.dir}` is expanded to "/tmp/docbase".  That's not true/on/yes/false/off/no so Ant *then* looks for a property named "/tmp/docbase".  It can't find it, so it runs the `unless`.

---

Here's an example that I hope will clarify things.  This will run only the `if` target:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="context" basedir=".">
    <target name="context">
        <echo>docbase: ${docbase.dir}</echo>
        <property name="/tmp/docbase" value="i exist!"/>
        <antcall target="_context.docbase"/>
        <antcall target="_context.nodocbase"/>
    </target>

    <target name="_context.docbase" if="${docbase.dir}">
        <echo>Context with docbase</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="_context.nodocbase" unless="${docbase.dir}">
        <echo>Context without docbase</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The important thing here is this line:

```
        <property name="/tmp/docbase" value="i exist!"/>
```

Because that property is defined, it will run the `if` and not the `unless`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the subtlety, but I don't see how this is any better off.  Clearly my 'docbase.dir' is parameterized so you're saying I need to create a new property with the name of the value my parameter, but I need to do it conditionally, so I'm back to square one.

Comment: I wasn't presenting a solution, I was just presenting proof to back up what I was saying and explain the problem by example.

Comment: @rjcarr the fact of the matter is you can't use `if` or `unless` the way you're trying to.  It accepts "true/on/yes/false/off/no/or the name of a declared parameter".  Those are your only options.

Comment: @rjcarr but if you want a different solution, you can use this: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html

Comment: OK, thanks again for the explanation and showing why it won't work the way I'm trying.